# cookies.signed[:auth_token] cleared on redirect in Rails test environment only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec

I have a blog post with comments. The controller looks like this (with some extraneous stuff removed):

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new comment_params.merge( user: current_user )
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @comment.post and return
  else
    flash.now 'Comment Error'
    redirect_to @comment.post and return
  end
end
```

So far, so good. All works as expected, in the browser: when I submit a comment that's too short (triggering a validation error), I get the flash message and end up back on the `posts/show` page.

However, when I run an Rspec test for the very same functionality, my cookies and session are getting cleared. When I land back on the `posts/show` page, I'm logged out and there's no flash. Not what I want.

Here's the failing test (which fails on the `have_flash` line):

```
scenario 'should not create a new comment if it is too short' do
  sign_in @user
  visit post_path(@post)

  new_comment = 'too short'
  within 'form#new_comment' do
    fill_in 'comment_body', with: new_comment
    click_on 'Comment'
  end

  expect(page).to have_flash 'Comment Error'
  expect(page).not_to have_content new_comment
end
```

Any idea why my session and cookies would get cleared on a redirect in test, but not in development?